# White out pictures outdoors

Tags: canon, powershot

We have a Canon Power Shot A 470,after changing the batteries all outdoor pictures are only white, some inside pictures are fine. What can we do?

Comment: Could you post the shutter speed, aperture and ISO the photos were taken with? Upload them to your computer and they should be available with the photo viewer in the operating system.

Comment: What "mode" is the camera set to? Is that the mode you are used to using?

Comment: We have a point and shoot camera so we do not set any speed or aperture and apparently the camera can not be fixed. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Even if you can't directly *control* the exposure parameters, the camera reports what it used when the shot was taken in the EXIF info attached to each photo. This information can be used to diagnose what the issue might be.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the camera on an automatic mode?